# Как задать самостоятельно размер heap

Tags: java, heap

Доброго времени суток. Мне надо уменьшить размер heap. Проблема в том, что я знаю как это сделать через глобальную конфигурацию java или через запуск проги через терминал, но это не то, что я бы хотел делать каждый раз при запуске. Может есть способ указать значение размера кучи до билда, а после, чтобы оно использовалось всегда по умолчанию?

Comment: где вы хотите его указать?

Comment: @Viktorov в этом по сути и вопрос. Могу сказать только то, что мне нужна это конфигурация конкретно для моей программы

Comment: А если создать ярлык на ваш jar и указать в нем ключи для JVM ?

Comment: @Viktorov ярлыку надо определённое расположение, за что я не ручаюсь

Comment: Кроме параметров запуска JVM, есть только один способ управлять размером кучи - собрать собственную JVM из предварительно исправленных должным образом исходников.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java

Comment: @Aleksandr он же написал, что ему не подходит вариант с заданием размера кучи через аргументы командной строки.